# Power BI first IF-Statement then the DAX-Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI and have the following issue:

I tried to build a formula for a frequency counter. I got some examples from the web and I was able to build this working formula. The basic idea behind is to categorize an item with the values: daily, weekly or first time.

I tried to add an IF-Statement to the formula, that is checking a calculated column "*Time frame*", which shows the duration of an item in minutes.

Basically it should run this formula only if the Column "*Time frame*" is equal or bigger **1**.

Now the formula gives to items with a Time frame of **0**, the value first time. But they should be ignored or blanked.

```
Calculated column = 
Var freqcount =
COUNTAX(FILTER(ALL('Count'),
AND([Date]>=DATEADD('Count'[Date],-6,DAY)&&[Date]<=EARLIER([Date]),[ID]=EARLIER('Count'[ID]))),ID]) 
return
if(freqcount>=4,"Daily",if(freqcount>=2,"Weekly",if(freqcount>=1,"First time","Inactive")))
```

I would be thankful, if someone could support me with this issue.

Edit: an ID can occur multiple times in my table but with different dates. But only once with the same date. For example:

1. ID 1, Date 01.01.2020
2. ID 1, Date 02.01.2020
3. ID 1, Date 03.01.2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easier to use calculate:

```
Calculated column =
    var rDate = yourTable[Date]
    var rID = yourTable[ID]
    var freqCount = CALCULATE(yourTable('Count'), FILTER(yourTable, rDate >= DATEADD(yourTable[Date], -6 , DAY) && rID = yourTable[ID] && yourTable['Time frame'] > 0))
return if(freqcount>=4,"Daily",if(freqcount>=2,"Weekly",if(freqcount>=1,"First time","Inactive")))
```

you see how I simply added the Time frame to the expression. Also I removed the use of earlier by using var's so it is better readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get an error in the following parts of your formula: `var freqCount = CALCULATE(COUNT('Count')` - I replace the count with my table name and it says: Parameter is not the correct type. If i replace it with 'Count'[ID] it says: Too few arguments were passed to the FILTER function. 
 Second error: `FILTER(rDate >= DATEADD('Count'[Date], -6 , DAY) && rID = 'Count'[ID] && 'Count'[Time Frame] > 0))` Also the same error. And Power BI displays: The COUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument. Do you have a solution for those errors?

Comment: I should add that an ID can occur multiple times in my table but with different dates. For example: ID 1, Date 01.01.2020 - ID 1, Date 02.01.2020. But only once with the same date. I will update my post.

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the answer (do not have PowerBi on this machine). I missed teh table to filter as first argument for Filter..

Comment: On your comment about the ID, this is why we filter also on the ID

Comment: Thanks Aldert for your answer. The formula is working now. But I another issue now to some values I get from. For example I have 3 rows with the ID 1 and it occurs on the dates 04.01.2020, 06.01 and 07.01. The dates 06 and 07 have the "Time Frame" of 0. The date 04.01 has 250. So, I get for the date 04.01 the value "First Time" and for the other 2 dates also the same value "First Time". So the "First Time" values are wrong for a "Time Frame" of 0. Same happens to other rows. 
Maybe you know a solution to this issue?

Comment: Then you need to take the last part out of the CALCULATE : && yourTable['Time frame'] > 0. And change the IF starting with an extr: IF (yourrTable['Time frame'] > 0, "Inactive", IF....  and you can take out the last IF.